# How to get all siblings between each table header using JQuery or Cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cheerio

I need to do a web scraping on a HTML page with a table with multiple table headers

E.g.:

```
<table class="tabledata">
  <th colspan="32"> TH1 </th>
  <tr>
    <td>TD11</td>
    <td>TD12</td>
    <td>TD13</td>
    ... ...
    <td>TD1N</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TD21</td>
    <td>TD22</td>
    <td>TD23</td>
    ... ...
    <td>TD2N</td>
  </tr>
  ... ...
  <th colspan="32"> TH2 </th>
  <tr>
    <td>TDfsf1</td>
    <td>TDasf2</td>
    <td>TDads33</td>
    ... ...
    <td>TDcvvN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TDafadf1</td>
    <td>TDujjj2</td>
    <td>TDnbnbn3</td>
    ... ...
    <td>TDppppaN</td>
  </tr>
  ... ...
  <th colspan="32"> TH3 </th>
  <tr>
    <td>TDfsf1</td>
    <td>TDasf2</td>
    <td>TDads33</td>
    ... ...
    <td>TDcvvN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TDafadf1</td>
    <td>TDujjj2</td>
    <td>TDnbnbn3</td>
    ... ...
    <td>TDppppaN</td>
  </tr>
  ... ...
  <th colspan="32"> TH12 </th>
  ... ...
</table>
```

This table has multiple  elements. Between  elements, there are sibling  elements. I would like to get all sibling  elements under each  element.

EDIT:
The HTML is just what it is. Having multiple  in the table could be wrong. But this is out of my control. One  has multiple s below it then another  comes below the  then another set of s follow.

Comment: your mark up is invalid as we cannot have `<th>` or `<td>` without `<tr>`

Comment: A 'sibling' is relative to something. You want to get the 'sibling' of what?

Comment: What kind of structure do you want to end up with? Perhaps an array containing arrays of elements?

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML Markup is wrong, please make sure you are writting valid HTML.

You can find elements by using jQuery like:

```
$('.tabledata').find('td');
```